# flutter: identify orientation when the screen is locked

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to google this yields thousands of unrelated articles, such as setting or locking a specific orientation.

My question is, while the orientation for the phone is locked in say, portrait mode, but the screen is turned sideways, is there way to detect this shift and adjust widgets on the screen in response?

Something like

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
      return Text('text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200));
    } else {
      return Text('flipped text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200));
    }
```

does not work. Same thing with `OrientationBuilder` - these seem to rely on what mode the phone thinks it's in.

I see there is the [sensors](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors) package and I'm sure I could get it to work eventually, but it kinda feels like killing a mosquito with a bazooka. I'm hoping there's something simple I've missed when trying to google this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so it wasn't that difficult using the sensors package after all. Just had to use the 2nd coordinate of the `accelerometer` values and compare whether it was greater than ~4 (I assume this is m/s^2, as the resting value was ~9).

So the added code is something like:

```
class _SampleScreenState extends State<SampleScreen> {
  //...
  List<double> _accelerometerValues;
  List<StreamSubscription<dynamic>> _streamSubscriptions =
      <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];

  //...

  void initState() {
    //...

    _streamSubscriptions
        .add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _accelerometerValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
      });
    }));
  }

  //...

  sampleWidget() {
    if (_accelerometerValues[1] > 4) {
      return Text('portrait');
    } else {
      return Text('landscape');
    }
  }

  //...
```

I will probably add some hysteresis to this to make it cleaner, but it's a working solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on trying to get this to work for hours and this is the only solution that actually gives the device orientation without dirty hacks or outdated packages.

Comment: just a second.. which package are you using???

Comment: Is there a way to get if the orientation is landscapeLeft or landscapeRight??

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to set your screen to landcape `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);` in `initState`
or `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portaitUp]);` for the portrait mode.

**Note:**
It might not work for iOS deviuce if youy don't add in the `Info.plist`
these lines

```
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't solve my problem. I can't allow the orientation to be changed - I should have specified that explicitly. I did discover the solution which wasn't so difficult using the sensors package so I will post the solution.

Comment: oh ok nice to hear that you found the solution!